# How to make two responsive columns inside the mat-card-content using fxLayout?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

Here is my **HTML** code snippet:

```
<mat-card-content>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxFlex="1 0 0">
        <div fxLayout="column">First</div>
        <div fxLayout="column" style="margin-left:auto">Second</div>
    </div>
</mat-card-content>
```

And **CSS**:

```
.mat-card-content {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.700);
}
```

I need to implement flex layouts inside the angular material card element so that two columns will responsive and will contain some text like in the magazine:
[image: img]

At this moment I have done mat-card-header and it's working right.
Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: I solved it like: `<mat-card-content>
      <div fxLayout="row" fxFlex="1 0 0" fxLayoutAlign="space-between" fxLayoutGap="15px">
<div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="1 0 0">My</div>
<div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="1 0 0">
          <ul>
<li></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
    </mat-card-content>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like below :

```html
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="10">
  <div fxFlex="50%">
 <p> first div </p>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex="50%">
      <p> second div </p>

    </div>
</div>
```

2022 update :

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bgmegr)

Answer (score 4):

you have try this code its working as you want

```
<mat-card-content>
      <div fxLayout="row" fxFlex="100" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center">
        <div fxLayout="column">First</div>
        <div fxLayout="column">Second</div>
      </div>
</mat-card-content>
```

for better understanding

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sozro8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want responsive for mobile device also, you can use flex-layout [Responsive API](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API).

```
<mat-card-content>
   <div fxLayout.gt-sm="row" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="16px">
       <div fxFlex.gt-sm="50%" fxFlex>
          First div
       </div>
       <div fxFlex.gt-sm="50%" fxFlex>
          Second div
       </div>
    </div>
</mat-card-content>
```